# найти индексы повторяющихся строк в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl

Есть задача найти номер повторяющихся строк в двумерном массиве. Повторяющимися считаются строки, у которых совпадают элементы в определенных позициях (количество таких позиций и сами позиции задаются пользователем, по сути это `std::vector<uint16_t> colsToCompare`). Мое решение задачи максимально тривиальное (тут просто идея алгоритма больше на псевдокоде):

```
std::unordered_set<uint32_t> rowsToRemove;
for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < end_row; j++)
    {
        bool equal = false;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < colsToCompare.size(); k++) 
        {
            GetCell(i, colsToCompare.at(k), cell1);
            GetCell(j, colsToCompare.at(k), cell2);
            equal = are_cells_equal(cell1, cell2);
            if (!equal)
                break;
        }
        if (equal) 
        {
            rowsToRemove.insert(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Алгоритм рабочий, но при большом количестве строк (около 1М) он очень медленный. Подскажите, может есть вариант используя какие-нибудь контейнеры stl решить задачу только с одним прохождением по строкам (то есть без цикла j)?

Comment: Записывайте выборку по нужным позициям в map, тогда время будет линейно от числа строк.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `map`, в котором ключом будет `tuple` из значений в нужных позициях, а значением вектор с номерами строк, который содержат эти позиции?

Comment: значение - не вектор, а просто номер строки

Comment: Но тогда у меня будет только номер одной строки, содержащей дубликаты. А мне нужно номера всех строк. Допустим, в массиве третья и пятая строка дублируют первую. Мне нужно получить индексы 3 и 5. А в случае, если значением будет только номер строки,  то у меня там будет только 5.

Comment: Из кода я так понял, что вы 3 и 5 сразу заносите в отдельный вектор номеров на удаление, необходимости в мапе хранить эти номера вроде нет? Собственно, и значение (номер строки) в таком случае не нужно, достаточно не map, а set

Comment: Да. Мне просто нужно получить вектор с номерами строк, которые нужно удалить. Удалить нужно строки-дубликаты. Основная проблема - быстро найти эти номера

Comment: Ну тогда set для хранения выборок, а rowsToRemove, как у вас и было - для номеров с повторами

Comment: Не понимаю идею. Как это поможет избежать вложенного цикла по строкам?

Comment: Добавил псевдокод ответом

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте сет, хранящий выборки нужных ячеек. Для каждой строки создаёте выборку, и проверяете, есть ли она уже в сете. Если есть - номер в список на удаление, если нет - добавляете в сет

```
set<tuple чего-то там> csets;
for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++) 
    tup = tuple(line[i], colsToCompare);
    if (tup in csets) 
        rowsToRemove.insert(j)
    else
        csets.insert(tup)
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую и отпишу